# different use of for loop in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I wanted to understand why the below 2 statement are treated differently in python.

```
for w in words:
```

and

```
for w in words[ : ]
```

Here is case where I found both the statement getting a different result. Consider the below code snippet :

```
words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
counter = 0
for w in words:  
    if len(w) > 6:
       words.insert(0, w)
print(words)
```

in the above snippet , if i use the way it shows, the program goes in a indefinite loop, where as, if i use `for w in words[ : ]:`, the program exits properly with output :

```
['defenestrate', 'cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
```

I was expecting both to produce similar results

Comment: Side-note: No one leaves [spaces in implicit parts of the slice notation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements). It's just `words[:]`.

Answer (score 0):

Fast answer

```
for w in words: # perates on actual object

for w in words[ : ] #operates on copy coz "[:]" is slicing whole array
```